# Complex (?) Unix Text Replace Command

Tags: unix, command-line, command

What's the command line equivalent of:
For every file that contains "AAA" within its contents, find "BBB" and replace it with "CCC"

Thus, the command would match and replace BBB in a file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
AAA
Hello world!
BBB    
</body>
</html>
```

But Not in a file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Don't match me!
BBB    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `grep -l AAA file-names | xargs sed -i .bak 's/BBB/CCC/g'` should work.  In the future, you might want to ask questions like this on https://serverfault.com/ instead.

Comment: Can I replace file-names with *.* to go through all files? what's the .bak about? I've already made backups.

Comment: Thanks! I asked elsewhere and got the following. What does yours do differently? :::  grep -Rl AAA . | xargs sed -i -e 's/BBB/CCC/'

Answer (score 0):

Using positive look behind also can do the trick `s/(?<=AAA).*?(BBB)/CCC/g`.